# Construir Lambda Expression complexa

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Estou tentando construir uma Lambda Expression que é um pouco complexa e estou tendo dificuldades.

O objetivo é esta expressão:

```
items = items.Where(x => sValues.Any(y => x.Contract_Rates.Select(z => z.CostCenterId).Contains(y)));
```

Porém, em `RunTime`, eu não sei o nome da lista que no exemplo é `Contract_Rates`, a questão é que preciso varrer as coleções de um objeto, já possuo um método que preenche a variável `Collections` (exibido no código abaixo) e verificar se esta é uma coleção que implementa `IHasCostCenter`, caso positivo, efetuar a `Lambda Expression` citada.

O que tenho até agora é:

```
var sValues = User.CostCenters.Select(x => x.CostCenterId).ToList();

ParameterExpression Parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Contrato), "x");

foreach (var item in Collections.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y == typeof(IHasCostCenter))))
{
    // Obtenho o nome da lista (i.e. 'Contract_Rates')
    var PropertyName = typeof(T).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains(item.Name)).Name;

    Expression Property = Expression.Property(Parameter, typeof(T).GetProperty(PropertyName));
    LambdaExpression Column = Expression.Lambda(Property, Parameter);
    Expression Select = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Select",
        new Type[] { items.ElementType, Column.Body.Type },
        items.Expression,
        Column);

    Expression Contains = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        "Contains",
        new[] { sValuesType },
        Expression.Constant(sValues, sValues.GetType()),
        Select);

    MethodCallExpression Where = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { items.ElementType },
        items.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda(Contains, Parameter));

    items = items.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(Where);
```

Porém não consigo desenvolver corretamente como obtenho o SELECT da expressão `x.Contract_Rates.Select(y => y.CostCenterId)` e como obtenho o ANY da expressão `sValues.Any(y => x.Contrato_Rateios.Select(z => z.CentroCustoId).Contains(y))`

Qualquer ajuda será apreciada.

Comment: Por que necessariamente você precisa usar lambda expressions?

Comment: Eu não consigo usar `Lambda` normalmente pois não sei o nome dos atributos, não posso usar `Reflection` sem ser por `Lambda Expression`. E também não posso converter o objeto durante a utilização do `Lambda` (para `IHasCostCenter`, por exemplo) pois o objeto depois de convertido gera erro ao retornar para a entidade `T`. Você consegue ver alguma outra maneira?

Comment: Está me parecendo um código complicado demais pro que você quer fazer. Talvez entendendo a questão de um âmbito macro eu consiga te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @CiganoMorrisonMendez. A situação é a seguinte: Imagine que cada usuário tem uma lista de CostCenter (`sValues`). Baseado nessa lista eu preciso filtrar as tuplas das classes que ele pode ver, e isto só pode acontecer caso a entidade implemente IHasCostCenter, pois nem todas as classes precisam deste filtro, ao mesmo tempo que caso a classe pai não implemente IHasCostCenter mas alguma propriedade filha (ou lista, neste caso) implemente, eu preciso também filtrar as tuplas da classe pai pelas filhas. Entendeu?

Comment: Você não acha complicado demais filtrar a visibilidade de um registro usando uma interface? Eu usaria outra coisa que não Reflection pra isso.

Comment: esta pergunta está como ativa. Ela ainda precisa de uma resposta?

Comment: Olá @FernandoMondo, a questão ainda não foi resolvida, eu particularmente estou utilizando uma abordagem na qual é necessário o nome da propriedade, pois não achei solução para esta maneira específica.

Comment: Sua primeira expressão pode ser simplificada. Sei que não responde, mas as vezes pode ajudar na solução. `items = items.Where(x => sValues.Any(y => x.Contract_Rates.Any(z => z.CostCenterId == y));`

Answer (score 1):

A consulta que vocês está querendo construir, (talvez) não é (seja) necessária. Você pode atingir o mesmo resultado utilizando o `join` entre as coleções `items` e `sValues`.

Veja um exemplo a seguir:

```
var result = from x in items
             join y in sValues on x.Contract_Rates.Select(z => z.CostCenterId).Contains(y)
             select x;
```

**Edit 1**

Após seu comentário, entendi melhor o seu problema. Talvez seja mais fácil resolver o seu problema com OOP (se você tiver acesso a classe da coleção `Items`). A alternativa seria:

Nas classes que devem disponibilizar esse comportamento, você implementa uma interface obrigando a disponibilização de um método (que você sempre saberá o nome) para obter a coleção IHasCostCenter:

```
public interface IHasCostCenterAvailable {

   IHasCostCenter GetIHasCostCenterCollection();

   // outra opção
   //IHasCostCenter IHasCostCenterCollection {get;set;}
}

public class CollectionItems: IHasCostCenterAvailable {

   IHasCostCenter GetIHasCostCenterCollection()
   {
      return this.Contract_Rates;
   }
}


public class OutraCollectionItems: IHasCostCenterAvailable {

   IHasCostCenter GetIHasCostCenterCollection()
   {
      return this.OutroNomeQualquerDeColecao;
   }
}


// Exemplo de preenchimento
var items = new List<IHasCostCenterAvailable>();
items.Add(new CollectionItems());
items.Add(new OutraCollectionItems());

// Nova consulta.
var result = from x in items
             join y in sValues on x.GetIHasCostCenterCollection().Select(z => z.CostCenterId).Contains(y)
             select x;
```

Nessa segunda sugestão, você não se importa com os nomes das coleções, porque você vai acessar a coleção desejada sempre pela interface `IHasCostCenterAvailable`. Sendo assim, o seu problema, saber o nome da coleção, acaba.

**Edit 2**
Caso você não tenha acesso a classe da coleção `items` diretamente, existem algumas outras formas de acessá-la, que poderiam ser através de:

- padrão Visitor;
- methods extensions;
- reflexão.

Comment: Primeiramente gostaria de agradecer a ajuda. Posso até tentar esta abordagem, a questão é que através da expressão inicial (`items = items.Where(x => sValues.Any(y => x.Contract_Rates.Select(z => z.CostCenterId).Contains(y)));`) eu obtenho o resultado necessário. Eu só não consigo montar a expressão dinamicamente, nos casos em que eu não sei o nome da propriedade que contém a lista de `IHasCostCenter`. No exemplo eu deixo claro que é a propriedade `Contract_Rates`, mas dinamicamente eu não vou saber.

Comment: Veja o segundo exemplo que disponibilizei agora. Talvez ele possa te ajudar.